# Using recursion to reverse even indices of a String

Tags: java, string, recursion, reverse

For this part of my recursive method I need to handle the case of an even length string greater than 2 (as shown in my base cases). My issue is figuring out how to make my recursive case actually approach my base cases. I'm not sure if I did the reversing part correctly either, as I get a Stack Overflow error due to the base cases never being hit.
Here's the method in question. (I will handle the odd Strings after my current 'if' statement. I have "return null;" there at the moment so I can test my even case without the odd.)

EDIT: 
Example input: ABCDEF
Example output: EBCDAF

```
public static String revEven(String inString)
   {
      String tempString = new String();

      if (inString.length() <= 2)
         return inString;
      if (inString.length() == 3)
         {
         tempString += inString.charAt(2);  
         tempString += inString.charAt(1);
         tempString += inString.charAt(0);

         return tempString;
         }
      if (inString.length() % 2 == 0)
         {
         return revEven(inString.substring(0, inString.length() - 1) + inString.charAt(inString.length() - 1));
         }
      return null;
   }
```

Comment: "...as I get a Stack Overflow error..." -- Oh don't try to sweet talk us now...

Comment: Haha, I wish I was. I understand why I'm getting the error. Just everything I've tried to approach the base case makes even less sense than my current solution.

Comment: java.lang.StackOverflowError on the last return statement. I did say that, though. I also said I understood why it was happening. It's because the String I input into the recursive method never gets smaller, so it never hits a base case, causing my method to call itself forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you get StackOverflowError is that your string doesn't change between recursive calls. In the line where you call the function again you just recreate initial string.

"ABCD" = "ABC" (substring (0,3)) + "D" (charAt(3)) - the same string.

Hint. Don't try to change the string in recursive calls. 
Probably, it's better to represent your string as array of chars, change indices in recursive calls and then swap chars in place which are pointed by even indices.

I didn't check corner cases but the idea is below:

```
public static String runEven(String string) {
     char[] array =  runEvenImpl(string.toCharArray(), 0, string.length());
     return new String(array);
}

public static char[] revEvenImpl(char[] array, int head, int tail) {
      if (head == tail)
         return array;
      if (head % 2 == 0 && tail % 2 == 0)
      {
           swap(array, head, tail);
      }
      revEven(array, head+1, tail-1);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. My prof said not to use an array for this. That's why I chose to use the substring and charAt methods.

Comment: @CoinBird If you can't use array/indices then you can't use charAt() which is just fancy name for index in the underlying char array.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you said to transfer each character to an array. We're supposed to keep it as a String. Any switching of chars is to be done with string concatenation. charAt and substring methods are allowed.